# Why does `.retain()` not work chained with `.iter()`?

Tags: rust

I'm wondering why the below code does not remove all the empty strings:

```rust
fn set_name_list(&mut self, mut name_list: Vec<String>) {
    // name_list is ["     "]

    name_list
        .iter()
        .map(|o| trim_all_spaces(o))
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .retain(|o| !o.is_empty());

    // name_list is ["     "] here
}
```

but this works instead:

```rust
fn set_name_list(&mut self, mut name_list: Vec<String>) {
    // name_list is ["     "]

    name_list = name_list
        .iter()
        .map(|o| trim_all_spaces(o))
        .collect::<Vec<String>>();

    name_list.retain(|o| !o.is_empty());

    // name_list is correctly [] here
}
```

Why does `.retain()` not work chained with `.iter()`?

Comment: By the way, instead of doing `collect` and then `retain` you should replace `map` with `filter_map`

Comment: @PatientPenguin can you write an example?

Answer (score 3):

You can't in fact call `retain()` on an iterator, because it's not defined for iterators, but instead for the collections directly as you can see when you [search for it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=retain).

What your first snippet does is instead `collect` into a **new** and **temporary** vector, and call `retain` on that, for obvious reasons this cannot remove any elements from the original.

Your second version works because you overwrite the original vector with the one you newly collect. Since you've stored it you can of course call `retain` on it and it works.

In your case you can use a single `retain_mut` call to do all the modification and removal in one go, and inplace:

```rust
fn set_name_list(mut name_list: Vec<String>) {
    name_list.retain_mut(|o| {
        trim_all_spaces_inplace(o);
        !o.is_empty()
    });
}

fn trim_all_spaces_inplace(this: &mut String){
    // this inplace implementation is from this forum thread
    let trimmed = this.trim();
    let trim_start = trimmed.as_ptr() as usize - this.as_ptr() as usize;
    let trim_len = trimmed.len();
    if trim_start != 0{
        this.drain(..trim_start);
    }
    this.truncate(trim_len);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because the `.retain()` modifies the collection it is applied to, so it is important to directly invoke it on the vector itself instead of an iterator. In the initial code snippet, the function is called on an iterator created by `.iter()`, which does not alter the original vector. However, in the subsequent code snippet, the transformed vector is reassigned to `name_list` before utilizing `.retain()`, resulting in the vector being correctly modified!